# Highcharts, Change the Maximum Blocks Border Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to solve a way to be able to visually pickout blocks with the highest value from a column stack.
I was thinking one way to do that, while keeping the background color of the block, is to
add a border color for the block(s) with the maximum value, red for example.

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/luis9xx/ehBtQ/.  It's pretty much the same one in the highcharts demo gallary

I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/Z5VPw/ for changeing the color specific of a column to another color.  But the way the dataset is done is different, not sure if need to use a similar scheme set to outline the border color.

Also, I looked through the highcharts api and can't seem to find a clear path to what I'm trying to do.

So far, there's two parts

- Part 1 : Identify the maximum block(s) in a  column stack.
- Part 2 : Change the border for maximum block in the stack to red

  - I found these attributes, but not sure where to put them
  - `borderWidth:5, borderColor:'Red'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1: you cna do it out of Highcharts, right? Create simple for() and check which column is the highest one

Part 2: Put this into point object, so for example, when you know which points are the highest set data in that format:

```
series: [{
    data: [ [1], [2], { y: 3, borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'red' }]
}, {
    data: [ { y: 3, borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'red' }, [1], [2]]
}, {
    data: [ [1], { y: 3, borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'red' }, [2]]
}]
```